# Is it possible to set up a wireless bridge with DD-WRT?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, openwrt

I have a standard router (DLink) and a secondary Linksys running WRT. Currently I have it set up according to [this guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge). (using the instruction for DD-WRT v24 SP1 settings)

It works great, however it seems as though I can only connect via the actually ports in the router meaning it has to be hard wired.

Is it possible to set it up so that I can connect to the secondary router and still use it as a bridge? Seems like it doesn't work as a wireless AP anymore when its running in bridged mode.

Comment: @user: sounds very much like a non-programming question, but rather suited for SuperUser. Good luck!

Comment: DD-WRT doesn't function as an access point in bridge mode, if that's what you're asking.  And this question doesn't really belong on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to setup a client bridged mode with WRT which seems to be what you are looking for. First off read [this guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged) instead. Second, as per the guides first paragraph

> First of all, **do not even try to do client bridge with dd-wrt SP1.** It won't work. Also if you can't get Client Bridged to work on your hardware then try [Client Mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode) instead.

So you will want to upgrade to the latest version of DD-WRT. After that it is pretty straight forward. At the end of the guide you should be able to bridge the routers, and connect wireless and wired clients to each AP.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless chipsets cannot join multiple APs or any combination of APs and ad hoc clients at the same time, with one radio.  You need two wireless routers.